# How can I sort only some children of an element?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a scenario where I want to sort only some of the children of an element. Namely, I want to sort the children that have the attribute `Sorted="1"` according to the `field` attribute but not those that have `Sorted="0"`.

#### Input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <Row field="G" Sorted="1" />
  <Row field="A" Sorted="1" />
  <Row field="B" Sorted="0" />
  <Row field="H" Sorted="1" />
  <Row field="D" Sorted="1" />
  <Row field="M" Sorted="0" />
  <Row field="U" Sorted="1" />
  <Row field="W" Sorted="1" />
  <Row field="Z" Sorted="0" />
  <Row field="L" Sorted="1" />
  <Row field="A" Sorted="0" />
  <Row field="W" Sorted="1" />
</root>
```

#### Current XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each select="/Row[@Sorted='1']">
        <xsl:sort select="@field" order="ascending"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each select="/Row[@Sorted='0']">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

#### Desired Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <Row field="A" Sorted="1" />
  <Row field="D" Sorted="1" />
  <Row field="G" Sorted="1" />
  <Row field="H" Sorted="1" />
  <Row field="L" Sorted="1" />
  <Row field="U" Sorted="1" />
  <Row field="W" Sorted="1" />
  <Row field="W" Sorted="1" />
  <Row field="B" Sorted="0" />
  <Row field="M" Sorted="0" />
  <Row field="Z" Sorted="0" />
  <Row field="A" Sorted="0" />
</root>
```

Comment: What you do here is copy your root node twice, which will result in a xml document that is not wellformed, you can only have one root element per document.

Comment: @Louis, I updated the question as you suggested

Comment: @addisu Thanks for updating it. I've edited it to convey better what you are asking. In the desired output if the blank line between sorted and unsorted is only for illustration purposes to clearly delimit the two groups and you don't care about getting a blank line in your output, you should state it in your question. Not a big deal but it is better to be precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*In response to your updated question:*

> Sort Rows with Sorted=1 and copy them at the top and Copy the rest
>   Rows with Sorted=0 at the bottom of the xml unsorted

This can be done quite simply as:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Row[@Sorted='1']">
            <xsl:sort select="@field" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Row[@Sorted='0']"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="Row[@Sorted='1']">
            <xsl:sort select="@field" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="Row[@Sorted='0']">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```